# Convert HDF5 LiDAR data (from GEDI) to LAS or LAZ

Tags: python, remote-sensing, lidar, lidar-full-waveform, gedi

I downloaded GEDI LiDAR data in `hdf5` format. How can I open this file or convert it to the standard LAS format (point cloud)?

When I tried opening the `hdf` file with `QGIS`  and I got the following error:

> Invalid Layer: Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URL:filename)

I also tried opening it with `Python`:

```py
import pandas as pd
pandas.read_hdf('filename')
```

I got this error

```
ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file
```

[Link to the GEDI datapool.](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/GEDI/GEDI01_B.001/)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I'm able to add the data to ArcMAP and it asks which subdataset to add but it doesn't display. You can also use the Extract Subdataset tool to isolate one dataset.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about QGIS or pandas in this particular question. You can always ask about the other in a separate question and include links between them to keep them related.

Comment: This site operates under a [Code of Conduct](https://gis.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: Which is the exact file (link or name) you downloaded from GEDI?

Comment: @RafDouglas it's the same with all of them https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/GEDI/GEDI01_B.001/2019.04.18/GEDI01_B_2019108002011_O01959_T03909_02_003_01.h5 .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not possible to convert GEDI `.h5` file to LAS file as including all data. Because `.h5` file includes a lot of information about a point. Also, since LAS file has certain attributes for a point not matching attributes/values in `.h5` file, you cannot add all information to LAS file. For example, which value in `.h5` file does match `Z` value in LAS file, `elevation_bin0` or `elevation_lastbin`? Etc.

There is no one way/method to convert any `.h5` file to another format. It depends on data structure included in `.h5` file. It varies from `.h5` to `.h5`. Therefore, you should decide the attributes you would like to use.

Using **[`h5py`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html)** package, you can easily read `h5` file. Firstly, let's examine GEDI .h5 file structure.

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_path = "path/to/GEDI01_B_2019108002011_O01959_T03909_02_003_01.h5"
f = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')
print(list(f.keys()))

# OUT
# ['BEAM0000', 'BEAM0001', 'BEAM0010', 'BEAM0011', 'BEAM0101', 'BEAM0110', 'BEAM1000', 'BEAM1011', 'METADATA']
```

There are 8 `BEAMXXXX` groups and 1 `METADATA` group. Now, let's see all datasets in all groups.

```
def get_h5_structure(f, level=0):
    """    prints structure of hdf5 file    """
    for key in f.keys():
        if isinstance(f[key], h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset):
            print(f"{'  '*level} DATASET: {f[key].name}")
        elif isinstance(f[key], h5py._hl.group.Group):
            print(f"{'  '*level} GROUP: {key, f[key].name}")
            level += 1
            get_h5_structure(f[key], level)
            level -= 1
        
        if f[key].parent.name == "/":
            print("\n"*2)

get_h5_structure(f)

### OUTPUT: (removed some lines) ###
# GROUP: ('BEAM0000', '/BEAM0000')
#   DATASET: /BEAM0000/all_samples_sum
#   GROUP: ('ancillary', '/BEAM0000/ancillary')
#     DATASET: /BEAM0000/ancillary/master_time_epoch
#     DATASET: /BEAM0000/ancillary/mean_samples
#     DATASET: /BEAM0000/ancillary/smoothing_width
#   DATASET: /BEAM0000/beam
#   DATASET: /BEAM0000/channel
#   DATASET: /BEAM0000/delta_time
#   GROUP: ('geolocation', '/BEAM0000/geolocation')
#     DATASET: /BEAM0000/geolocation/altitude_instrument
#     DATASET: /BEAM0000/geolocation/altitude_instrument_error
#     DATASET: /BEAM0000/geolocation/bounce_time_offset_bin0
#     ...
#
# GROUP: ('BEAM0001', '/BEAM0001')
# ...
#  
# GROUP: ('METADATA', '/METADATA')
#   GROUP: ('DatasetIdentification', '/METADATA/DatasetIdentification')
```

**NOTE:** I will use datasets in 'BEAM0000' as an example. For other BEAMXXXX group, you should change `group` variable.

```
group = "BEAM0000"

# number_of records
n = f[group]["all_samples_sum"].shape[0]
print(n)
# OUT: 249810
```

Let's find the keys which have 249810 (`n`) records. We'll form a DataFrame using these keys. Since there are two nested levels, two `for` loops are sufficient.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for k, v in f[group].items():
    if isinstance(v, h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset):
        if v.shape[0] == n:
            df[k] = v
    else: # if not dataset, it's group
        # iterate on datasets of the group
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
            if v2.shape[0] == n:
                df[k2] = v2

print(df.head())

### OUTPUT
#    all_samples_sum   beam  channel    delta_time   altitude_instrument  ...  tx_gloc  tx_gloc_error  tx_pulseflag  tx_sample_count  tx_sample_start_index  
# 0         16167838     0        0   4.078333e+07        411250.214378  ...      0.0            0.0             0              128                      1
# 1         16165121     0        0   4.078333e+07        411250.181709  ...      0.0            0.0             0              128                    129
# 2         16180451     0        0   4.078333e+07        411250.149040  ...      0.0            0.0             0              128                    257
# 3         16181775     0        0   4.078333e+07        411250.116372  ...      0.0            0.0             0              128                    385
# 4         16159591     0        0   4.078333e+07        411250.083705  ...      0.0            0.0             0              128                    513
# [5 rows x 77 columns]
```

`surface_type`, `rxwaveform` and `txwaveform` are missing. As far as I understand, `rxwaveform` and `txwaveform` are the most important keys in data.

Let's add `surface_type`, `rxwaveform` and `txwaveform` to `df`. Please note that each is not a single value, but a list about one point. (See the last 3 columns)

```
df["surface_type"] = [s_type for s_type in zip(*f[group]["geolocation"]["surface_type"][:,:])]

rxwaveform = f[group]["rxwaveform"][:]
rx_sample_count = f[group]["rx_sample_count"][:]
rx_split_index = f[group]["rx_sample_start_index"][:]-1
df["rxwaveform"] = [ rxwaveform[x:x+i] for x, i in zip(rx_split_index, rx_sample_count) ]

txwaveform = f[group]["txwaveform"][:]
tx_sample_count = f[group]["tx_sample_count"][:]
tx_split_index = f[group]["tx_sample_start_index"][:]-1
df["txwaveform"] = [ txwaveform[x:x+i] for x, i in zip(tx_split_index, tx_sample_count) ]

print(df)

# OUTPUT
#          all_samples_sum  beam  channel    delta_time  altitude_instrument   altitude_instrument_error  .....  tx_pulseflag  tx_sample_count   tx_sample_start_index                  rxwaveform                   txwaveform      surface_type  
#  0              16167838     0        0  4.078333e+07        411250.214378                    0.223205  .....             0              128                       1   [245.59883, 245.52516,...    [246.21742, 246.26566,...   (0, 1, 0, 0, 0)  
#  1              16165121     0        0  4.078333e+07        411250.181709                    0.223205  .....             0              128                     129   [246.6961, 247.62282, ...    [246.30019, 245.81613,...   (0, 1, 0, 0, 0)  
#  ...                 ...   ...      ...           ...                  ...                         ...  .....           ...              ...                     ...                         ...                          ...               ...  
#  249808         16103852     0        0  4.078712e+07        423272.175929                    0.213935  .....             0              128                31975425   [245.15685, 245.5818, ...    [247.31981, 247.07133,...   (0, 1, 0, 0, 0)  
#  249809         16123677     0        0  4.078712e+07        423272.235064                    0.213935  .....             0              128                31975553   [245.64854, 244.94704,...    [247.12299, 247.5319, ...   (0, 1, 0, 0, 0)  
#  
#  [249810 rows x 80 columns]
```

I don't know what these values mean, therefore, how to use `df` is up to you.

---

All necessary script:

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_path = "path/to/GEDI01_B_2019108002011_O01959_T03909_02_003_01.h5"
f = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')

group = "BEAM0000"
n = f[group]["all_samples_sum"].shape[0]

df = pd.DataFrame()    
for k, v in f[group].items():
    if isinstance(v, h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset):
        if v.shape[0] == n:
            df[k] = v
    else: # if not dataset, it's group
        # iterate on datasets of the group
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
            if v2.shape[0] == n:
                df[k2] = v2
                
rxwaveform = f[group]["rxwaveform"][:]
rx_sample_count = f[group]["rx_sample_count"][:]
rx_split_index = f[group]["rx_sample_start_index"][:]-1
df["rxwaveform"] = [ rxwaveform[x:x+i] for x, i in zip(rx_split_index, rx_sample_count)]

txwaveform = f[group]["txwaveform"][:]
tx_sample_count = f[group]["tx_sample_count"][:]
tx_split_index = f[group]["tx_sample_start_index"][:]-1
df["txwaveform"] = [ txwaveform[x:x+i] for x, i in zip(tx_split_index, tx_sample_count)]

df["surface_type"] = [s_type for s_type in zip(*f[group]["geolocation"]["surface_type"][:,:])]
```

---

If you prefer, you can save `df` as shapefile.

```
import geopandas as gpd

# 2000 sample records
df2 = df[-6000:-4000]

# convert lists to string not to get error
df2['rxwaveform'] = df2['rxwaveform'].apply(str)
df2['txwaveform'] = df2['txwaveform'].apply(str)
df2['surface_type'] = df2['surface_type'].apply(str)

geometries = gpd.points_from_xy(df2.longitude_bin0, df2.latitude_bin0)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=geometries)
gdf.crs = 'EPSG:4326' # WGS84
gdf.to_file("c:/path/to/output.shp")
# OR 
# gdf.to_file("c:/path/to/output.gpkg", layer=group, driver='GPKG')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It does not convert the HDF5 to LAS, but it gives a great point to start. I think exporting the dataframe and using  `text2las` would do the trick.

Comment: I've added a script which converts dataframe to shapefile. I guess it's more useful for some users than LAS. I've used `longitude_bin0` and `latitude_bin0` as coordinates.

Comment: When I run the script I get the error: "KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'all_samples_sum' doesn't exist)"" and unfortunately I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @FelixB. It means your file doesn't contain `all_samples_sum` data.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, yes, that's clear to me, I've also been able to understand that. Maybe I should have written more concisely why my data doesn't contain an all_sample_sum like in the example. I'm using version 2 of the Level1B data and suspect that's the reason.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the *rhdf5* library within R to open the *.h5* file and then tie each attribute you are interested in to the collocated coordinates. Then, output the data in *ASCII* or *.csv*. This will let you import the relevant data as a point cloud in QGIS. I would also recommend looking into CloudCompare software for any point cloud analysis. Below is a sample of the code I wrote to handle this:

```
library(rhdf5)

#You can view the attribute information by using this method
h5ls(file.choose())

#Once you find the attribute you are looking for, use the path to
#direct the h5read function by setting it to the name variable
h5ImageAttribute <- h5read(file = file.choose(), name = "attributeName")
h5ImageY <- h5read(file = file.choose(), name = "attributeLatY")
h5ImageX <- h5read(file = file.choose(), name = "attributeLonX")
h5ImageZ <- h5read(file = file.choose(), name = "attributeHeightZ")

df <- data.frame(h5ImageAttribute, h5ImageY, h5ImageX, h5ImageZ)

write.table(df, file = fileName.xyz, append = T, row.names = F)
```

You will need some information on the attribute data in order to direct the *h5read* function, but this will all be included within the *.xml* data. If you are alright with it being in *.xyz* format, this should serve you well.

Edit: Updated code and reference to *.las* and *.xyz* file formats